# Big Query not allowing to create table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table in Big Query out of a csv file that I have already stored in Google Cloud Storage, it has approx. 65MB. Already checked resources such as this one here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

However the "Create Table" is not clickable. I'm getting no error messages, no red warnings, just a not clickable button. Any ideas on what could be happening?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Here print with table name:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed "Nome de tabela". You have to give your table baby a name.

Comment: With or without name it stays the same, I added an EDIT up there

Comment: Try refresh the page, if it still doesn't work. Try `bq mk` from commandline to see if it works or gives you some error message to dig into. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

Comment: On my machine, the button will light up when GCS bucket is picked and table is named (just set expectation of correct behavior)

Comment: I can't believe it was only a refresh thing